# i want the class social to be visible to class tob- bar-selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want some help.
When  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) then my div with name social to be visible to class tob- bar-selection down from ul.
my html:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 640px):

.top-bar-section ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
<div class="instagram">
<a href="#">
<img src="  https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/assets/img/in.png">
</a>
</div>
<div class="facebook">
<a href="#">
<img src="  https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/assets/img/fb.png">
</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="top-bar-section">
<ul class="left home-active" data-position="2">
<ul class="center">
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr" target="_parent">Κεντρική</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr/i-etairia" target="_parent">Η Εταιρία</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr/upiresies" target="_parent">Υπηρεσίες</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr/proionta" target="_parent">Προϊόντα </a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr/katastima" target="_parent">Κατάστημα</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.testdomain.gr/test.gr/gr/contact" target="_parent">Επικοινωνία</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

In our cms the hamburger menu created by befault.

I search if i can do this with js but i dont find something to help me

Comment: Your css is wrong. `@media screen and (max-width: 640px){  }`.

Comment: i have not write all my css, but my css work

Comment: In the code you posted here you write the media query in the wrong mode....check it